# Error while receiving data from serial port

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have application with several windows (actually its two almost same windows with some functions). One of that function is reading data from COM port (read weight from weighting machine). Problem is that, it works perfect on first window, but when im closing it and opening another window, then clicking same function (lets call it calculate weight), im getting this error message:
Access to the port 'COM1' is denied.

Code:

```
   private void calculateWeight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sp = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    tekst = string.Empty;
    sp.Open();
    sp.WriteLine(((char)5).ToString());
    sp.WriteLine(((char)17).ToString());
    sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
}
private delegate void UpdateUi(string s);
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    tekst += sp.ReadExisting();
    if (tekst.Contains('S') && tekst.Length > 14)
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUi(czytajWage), tekst);
}
string tekst = string.Empty;

void czytajWage(string s)
{
    string w = "";
    for (int i = 5; i < 14; i++)
    {
        w += s[i];
    }
    MessageBox.Show(w);
    w = "";
    tekst = "";

    sp.DataReceived -= sp_DataReceived;
}
```

Anyone can help? ;)

Comment: Do you close the port when you close the window?

Comment: You cannot share a serial port.  Closing the SerialPort when the window closes and opening it again in another window is very troublesome as well.  Best practice here is to spin off the code that works with the SerialPort in a separate class and have only one instance of that class.  Separate the data from the view.

Answer (score 3):

Method `calculateWeight_Click` opens serial port. So I assume that you get your exception on `Open` call as [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open.aspx) states `UnauthorizedAccessException` can be thrown when:

> The current process, or another process on the system, already has the specified COM port open either by a SerialPort instance or in unmanaged code.

So solution for you is to `Close` and `Dispose` `sp` after you are done or use `IsOpen` if you want to reuse existing instance.